# Ubuntu 14.04 running slow on Compaq gq60 615dx 2009model

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, firefox, google-chrome

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a 2009 Compaq presario.  Everything (Firefox, Google Chrome, ubuntu itself) is running slow.  Any way I can speed things up? Just using this for accessing web content (Netflix, Youtube, and Grooveshark) which I watch through a projector using the VGA connection.  Its all working, but painfully slow.

I was running Windows 7, but my antivirus ran out and the system got all clogged with malware.  Maybe the malware is the problem?  Some annoying web pop-ups seem to have even followed me over via Chrome and Firefox.  I'm using chrome beta so I can watch Netflix.  Should I try to remove malware via Ubuntu?

I did nothing to remove Windows 7 before installing Ubuntu.  Should I have?

Here are my system's specs
Processor   2.0GHz AMD Athlon X2 Dual-Core QL-62
Memory  2GB DDR2
Hard drive  250GB 5,400rpm
Chipset     AMD RS780M
Graphics    256MB Nvidia GeForce 8200M
Operating System    Windows Vista Premium
Dimensions (WD)     14.9 inches wide by 9.9 inches deep
Height  1.7 inches high
Screen size (diagonal)  15.6 inches
System weight / Weight with AC adapter  6.2/7.1 pounds

Answer (score 0):

If you did what I did and installed it side by side, then yes your computer still can suffer from the malware from windows

Comment: OK, then how do I get windows off the machine?